# How can I pass an Array from one class to another?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I am trying to make the compiler pass the array from one of the classes to the main method. I don't know why it does not work, the code looks like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] board2;
        int userInput;
        playBoard = board.createBoard();
        userInput = takeAGuess.input();



    }

}





import java.util.Scanner;
public class takeAGuess {
        int input()
        {
            int input=0;
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter your guess now");
            input = reader.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Guess entered successfully");
            return input;
        }
}







public class board {
    int[] createBoard()
    {
        int[] board = new int[7];
        int randomNum =(int) (Math.random()*5);
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
        {
            board[randomNum+i] = 1;
        }
        System.out.println("Board created");
        return board;
    }
}
```

I already tried these lines:

```
new[] board = board.Createboard();
int board[] = board.Createboard();
{
  int board = new board();
  board  = createBoard();
}
```

I am aware of that I could easily put everything in one class and even one method but i'm to practice on using classes therefore I create lots of them.

Comment: please include your code as text in the question and not as a screenshot.

Comment: First of all , classes are named with a capital letter in Java. You shouldn't write an extra class for everything. If you use your class board just to create an array, just write a method in the main class, don't create an own class for that. The same for input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[] board2;
int userInput;
playBoard = board.createBoard();
userInput = takeAGuess.input();
```

where is **playboard** defined?

And... so much classes! Use methods in the **Main** class instead, it'll make your job lighter.